# Preventing an iFrame from refreshing upon adding a second iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, refresh

I'm developing a web-app which contains several iFrames. The frames can be added to the DOM at any point. I can successfully add the iFrame to the app currently, however, when the new iframe loads, the other iframes reload as well. In the case of a static webpage, this is fine, but in my app the iframes have widgets running, which becomes a big pain to have to manually restore their states.

Is there a way to prevent the original iframes from refreshing when the new iframe gets added in?

Original:

```
<iframe src="example.com" id="iframe1"></iframe>
document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.whatever
```

After something happens:

```
<iframe src="example.com" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="example.org" id="iframe2"></iframe>
```

iframe2 loads and iframe1 reloads

Preferred behavior:

iframe2 loads, iframe1 stays as it is until I explicitly call reload()

EDIT:

Run this on the console multiple times

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>';
```

A sample of this behavior can be seen in my window manager at

http://magnesiumbeta.com/Window.html (move the window somewhere else prior to adding a second one, to see them both refresh)

Comment: Adding an iframe to the DOM should not affect the state of existing iframes in any way: http://jsfiddle.net/eGAkU/ Can you supply a working example where this happens?

Comment: @ndm Now I'm officially confused.. the jsfiddle works, but my code project doesn't.. Hmm

Comment: @ndm I added a sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Appending* DOM content this way is not supported, what you are doing there with the `+=` operator on `.innerHTML` is *replacing* the nodes whole content with `current content + new content`, consequently all possible external resources are being reloaded as they are new content.

In order to avoid this you have to use the proper DOM method for appending child nodes, that is [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

or since you are already using jQuery, use its own [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
$(document.body).append('<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>');
```

Comment: :) sorry, you just kind of made my project go from completely broken to really cool